# Stacking Pair of Dell PC2724 Switches

Tags: dell, stacking, powerconnect

I have a pair of Dell PowerConnect 2724 switches that I'd like to stack. One switch will host components like the router, wi-fi access point, network printers, servers, etc. The other switch will be hosting various wired devices in a separate location. Reading through what I could find, I'm rather unclear as to what I need to do. I guess it doesn't help that I've gotten rusty on the more advanced concepts of network engineering, having not needed to deal with it for over a decade. Is there a guide on the steps needed to handle this in the most reliable fashion while also incorporating at least two cables for connection to increase throughput between switches? I want to make sure that there isn't too much of a bottleneck between the switches when there's a lot of simultaneous server access and internet access.

EDIT

I realize "stacking" might not be the most correct term for what I'm attempting to accomplish, but at the moment it's the closest term that I can think of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think the 2724 switches support stacking (making both chassis act as a single switch).

If more bandwidth is required than a single link provides, you can create a link aggregation group (LAG) with up to four ports:

> ### Aggregating Ports
>
> Link Aggregation optimizes port usage by linking a group of ports
> together to form a single LAG (aggregated group). Aggregating ports
> multiplies the bandwidth between the devices, increases port
> flexibility, and provides link redundancy. Consider the following when
> aggregating ports:
>
> - Link Aggregation is allowed between two devices
>   only.
> - All ports within a LAG must be the same media type.
> - A VLAN is not configured on the port.
> - The port is not assigned to a different LAG.
> - An available MAC address exists which can be assigned to a port.
> - Auto-negotiation mode is not configured on the port.
> - The port is in full-duplex mode.
> - All ports in the LAG have the same ingress filtering and tagged modes.
> - All ports in the LAG have the same back pressure and flow control modes.
> - All ports in the LAG have the same priority.
> - All ports in the LAG have the same transceiver type.
> - The device supports up to six LAGs, and up to four ports in each LAG.
>
> Ports added to a LAG do not their individual port configuration. When ports are removed from the LAG, the original port configuration is applied to the ports. The device considers an Aggregated Link a single logical port.

https://downloads.dell.com/manuals/all-products/esuprt_ser_stor_net/esuprt_powerconnect/powerconnect-2724_user%27s%20guide_en-us.pdf

[https://dl.dell.com/manuals/all-products/esuprt_ser_stor_net/esuprt_powerconnect/powerconnect-2724_user's%20guide2_en-us.pdf](https://dl.dell.com/manuals/all-products/esuprt_ser_stor_net/esuprt_powerconnect/powerconnect-2724_user%27s%20guide2_en-us.pdf)

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for. Just wasn't really sure what it was called or if the switches supported it.